# Active directory authentication and LDAP

Tags: windows, active-directory, authentication, ldap, kerberos

i am studying Active Directory directory services (AD) and all connected things (LDAP, kerberos, ...). I don't fully understand, how LDAP objects and AD interact between each other. So can you comment please my understanding of their interaction (which is written below):

There are some objects, that can authenticate in domain - most important of them are users and computers. Information(name in domain, permissions, some personal info, etc.) about this objects is stored in something, called  Global Catalog (GC), but authentication information (password hashes) is stored in SAM on Domain controller (DC). Let's consider, for example, that authentication in AD domain is based on Kerberos. So when user (or some other object) authenticates, he uses Kerberos protocol and starts interacting with DC and in authentication stage there is no LDAP. But when authentication stage is passed DC need to authorize this user, so for authorization DC uses LDAP storage (which can be local on DC or remote) and then, if user have permission to authenticate in domain, the kerberos ticket is granted (i omitted difficult process of gaining kerberos ticket, let's just consider that it's final stage). So then, when user wants to make some operation (for example read particular file or directory), the user's host is going to DC with request to operation and DC checks permissions in LDAP storage. If it's okay, then DC grants ticket to user  for particular operation (again, i have omitted difficult process of gaining ticket for gaining access to file/directory).

Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data lives in the LDAP directory which is itself a database with a certain schema for object types. As you mention certain object types (namely users, which computers inherit from) can authenticate to Active Directory through protocols like Kerberos.

The SAM only exists on machines that aren't Domain Controllers and is used to store local user information or cached credential authenticators (mostly unrelated). All Domain Controllers (with some exceptions) contain all user details and can authenticate any user within the domain and in effect don't need a SAM (some older components refer to AD itself as a SAM, but it's all just objects in LDAP these days).

All of the keys used by Kerberos live on the given user object or on special system objects like `krbtgt`. When a user is authenticated the KDC (Kerberos server portion) queries LDAP for the user, `krbtgt`, and resource (computer, service, etc.). The KDC then uses the keys on those queried objects to fulfill the protocol requirements.

So the basic process is something like this.

1. User joins their PC to the domain.
2. Domain creates a new computer object called `violetapple-pc$` and a password is set on that object.
3. User logs into the computer. Kerberos starts:
4. Computer finds a domain controller and sends an authentication request (AS-REQ) to the KDC on the DC. This request contains the username and authentication data. (see Kerberos RFC 4120 for specifics)
5. The KDC receives the request, finds the user in the LDAP directory and verifies the authentication data. It then finds the account `krbtgt` and generates a ticket-granting-ticket containing the user identity protected by the `krbtgt` secret. The TGT is returned to the computer.
6. Now the computer has the TGT, but it can't read it (computer doesn't have the secret). The computer sends a request the KDC for a service ticket to `violetapple-pc$` containing the TGT (TGS-REQ).
7. The KDC receives the request, validates the TGT, looks up the computer object and generates a ticket protected by the computer secret created in step 1. The ticket is returned to the computer.
8. The computer receives the ticket and has the secret from step 1, so it can decrypt the ticket. Within that ticket is all the information about the user (group membership, password expiration, etc.).

Everything handled by the DC and KDC all happen on the same machine, and in fact in the same process.

Comment: So, users' password hashes are stored as an objects in LDAP on DC?

Comment: As *properties* on the user object yes. Specifically in `SupplementalCredentials`. Normal query tools don't have permission to see that property so you can't examine them directly.

Comment: Ok, thank you for detailed answer!